# AuthenticationService.js 404 not found in Blazor Multi Application

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

When I try to use Authentication in my multi-WebAssembly Blazor applications, I receive the error that AuthenticationService.js is 404 not found.

The Blazor applications is working fine as the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982222/how-to-run-multiple-blazor-apps-in-single-website) or [here](https://github.com/javiercn/BlazorMultipleApps).

Also each Blazor application working fine if they are working from the root https://localhost even with authentication to my IdentityServer4.

Once I port them to https://localhost/FirstApp the following script is not working:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

I receive the 404 not found.

I think that `StaticWebAssetBasePath` does not load the `_cocntent`s as it should be.

**My Question is: How to load the **AuthenticationService.js** when working with multiple Blazor WebAssembly application without receiving the 404 not found?**

**I try the answer in this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21808#issuecomment-628563310) but with no luck**

**Edit**:
I have asked the same question [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39922) but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0) I have to add `first.UseStaticFiles("/FirstApp")` after the `first.UseStaticFiles()` when I `MapWhen` the WebAssembly FirstApp. Without this line DotNet Components will not load static files such as `<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>` and I will receive 404 Not found for them.